# PHP number Format with JSON

Tags: php, json

Hi guys and thank you so much for your support on the few weeks

i need to convert

```
{$data['rank']['points']}
```

to english notation (default) to shown as
1,235 rather than 1235

the data originates from an JSON file so data is being pulled every hour
the above variable is what is required to output the number

Comment: http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Answer (score 2):

See https://www.php.net/number_format

```
echo number_format($data['rank']['points']);
```

Example: http://3v4l.org/ih3lT

**Edit**: From your full code, I can see you're looking to embed this in a string.

So change this:

```
echo "    <td><strong>Military Points:</strong> {$data['rank']['points']}</td>\n";
```

To this:

```
echo "    <td><strong>Military Points:</strong> " . number_format($data['rank']['points'])  . "</td>\n";
```

Comment: Does the locale need to be set as well?

Comment: I believe you might get a decimal point or something else besides a comma if you do not set the proper settings.

Comment: No locale is needed if you just want the default behavior: "If only one parameter is given, number will be formatted without decimals, but with a comma (",") between every group of thousands." You can pass in additional args if you need to change the decimal point or thousands separator, but that's optional.

Comment: It defaults to US formatting, it appears.  You'd need to use http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.localeconv.php settings manually for other locales, but that's beyond this scope.  My mistake

Comment: this data is not shown with a database its JSON file which i $json = $json = file_get_contents($url); - {$data['rank']['points']} is the output needed to show the number data, i have tried the above and all it doe it repeat the content and bracket it as number_format(28282990) so it didnt work

Comment: @SimonHind {$data['rank']['points']} doesn't make any sense. Do you mean {'rank':{'points':'1234'}} or something like that? That would be accesible via $data['rank']['points']. Are you running your json data through `json_decode` (http://us1.php.net/json_decode) first?

Comment: @jszobody i done $data = json_decode($json, true); , this is the JSON file http://api.erpk.org/citizen/profile/3121752.json file

Comment: @SimonHind Super. So you don't need curly brackets anymore. It's $data['rank']['points'], not {$data['rank']['points']}. If you "echo $data['rank']['points']" do you get the number 1234? If so, then "echo number_format($data['rank']['points'])" is what you need.

Comment: i now get this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING

Comment: Need to see more of your code then, you have something going on that isn't apparent from what you've shared so far. Are you trying to embed this `number_format()` inside a string or something? Give the larger snippet of code, showing how you are trying to use this number and the number_format call

Comment: @jszobody thanks for the update, your suggest above works as i need it